# How to display imported html file in react component

Tags: html, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to display an html file inside a react component. After debugging in VS code, `setHtmlContent` is called and `htmlContent` is set to html string, but nothing is displayed on the screen, it should display `hello` from the html in the first example. But if I remove fetch and set html to a variable in the second example, it will display `hello` on the screen. Is there a mistake when I am importing the html file?

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-phoebe-cywd9s?file=/src/App.js

First example with fetch html.

**src/assets/html/en.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the HTML content from a file or URL
    fetch("../assets/html/en.html")
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => {
        setHtmlContent(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching HTML content:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }} />;
}
```

[image]

Second example with html as variable:

**src/App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const htmlContent = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>

    <body>
      <div class="et_pb_tab_content">
        <div class="page" title="Page 1">
          <div class="layoutArea">
            <div class="column">
              <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
  `;

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }} />;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the HTML you're setting valid HTML and properly structured?

Comment: Yes it is a valid HTML

Comment: I edited it to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is the working folder structure you have to set your HTML code inside a public directory path like `public/assets/html/en.html`

**src/App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the HTML content from the public directory
    fetch("/assets/html/en.html")
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setHtmlContent(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching HTML content:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }} />;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! The html is showing now, may I know why we are fetching `/assets/html/en.html` and not `public/assets/html/en.html`?

Comment: the public directory is usually set as the root directory for serving static assets. That means files inside the public directory can be accessed directly without specifying /public/ in the path.

Comment: Why doesn't it work if it is not inside `public` directory?

Comment: Files outside the public directory are not served as static assets. Instead, they're intended to be processed, bundled, or transformed by Webpack. For instance, JavaScript and CSS files are bundled, and images can be inlined or optimized. In the context of CRA, the public directory is specifically designated for static assets that should be served as-is without any processing. The development server is set up to recognize the public directory as the root for static files.